# Bootstrap, Table, Centering Button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table, within which I want to put a drop-down button.  I cannot center the button, and I have tried many things.  Is there a way to do this?

```
<table class = "table table-hover table-condensed">
<tr>
  <th class = "text-center">
    Test
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left">
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option2</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the class "text center" in this div. Here is codepen to [see](https://codepen.io/capozzic1/pen/GMyRjB):

```
<div class="button-group text-center">
```

Also take take away col-md-3 and text-left from the containing div's class

Comment: Thanks very much, Dream_Cap.  I see that it moves a little to the right, but its not centered.  How do I get it directly below the "Test" text?

Comment: Boom, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `col-md-3 text-left` and add `text-center` on parent div of button. check updated snippet below...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class = "table table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
          <th class = "text-center">
            Test
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="text-center">
              <div class="button-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option2</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
```